# Rerouting outbound traffic

Tags: networking, routing

Can I  reroute outbound traffic from a physical interface  to a virtual interface (created using `ifconfig`)?

Specifically, the goal here is to reroute all outbound traffic from a physical interface (example: `eth0`) to a virtual interface (example: `eth0:0`) such that I will create a proxy that listens on certain ports behind the virtual interface.

Answer (score 1):

`eth0:0` is not a virtual interface, it's the old way to assign multiple IPv4 addresses to a single interface (`eth0`). More modern tools like `ip addr` won't show `eth0:0`, and will just list all the addresses.

You cannot create "virtual interfaces" with `ifconfig`.

You can create all sorts of network interfaces with `ip`, though I doubt any of those will match your idea of "virtual interface".

What you want to do is called "transparent proxy". There are various ways to set up such a proxy.

If what you really want to do is to sniff traffic for a certain application (or set of applications), what I'd do instead is to create a network namespace (google), connect it up to the main network namespace with a virtual eth-pair, setup the main network namespace for routing or NAT.

In any case, this looks very much like an [XY-Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and you haven't described your X well enough (besides that it's some sort of proxy; but it's unclear a proxy for what kind of traffic, and what exactly it should do) to really give good recommendations.